# GoTo is not defined - in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I on the step F8 click. then say it Goto is not defined. I try to make a inputbox with a messagebox that me the answer give. And I try also to make code when the values not correct is. See, you where I make a mistake in my VBA code:

```
Sub TwoNumbersinputbox()

Dim bytAnswer1 As String
Dim bytAntwer2 As String
Dim Range As Byte
Dim strNumber1 As String
Dim strNumber2 As String
[C3] = "Number1"
[C4] = "Number2"

Start1:
strNumber1 = InputBox("Give number one?", "Invoer", 5, 567, 567)
   If IsNumeric(strNumber1) Then
   MsgBox "This must be Number1", vbCritical, _
   "Number1 input"
   GoTo strNumber1
   Else: [B2] = strNumber1
   End If

  If Not IsNumeric(strNumber1) Then
  MsgBox "there is error.", vbCritical, "Number2 input"
  bytAnwer1 = MsgBox("Start Again?", vbYesNo)
  If bytAnwer1 = vbYes Then GoTo Start
  End If

Start2:
strGetal2 = InputBox("Give Number2?", "Input", 5, 567, 567)
   If IsNumeric(strNumber2) Then
   MsgBox "This must be Number2 ", vbCritical, _
   "Number2 input"
   GoTo strNumber2
   Else: [B3] = strNumber2
 End If

  If Not IsNumeric(strGetal2) Then
  MsgBox "Is there an error.", vbCritical, "Number2 input"
  bytAnswer2 = MsgBox("Start Again?", vbYesNo)
  If bytAnswer2 = vbYes Then GoTo Start
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have several GoTo commands (GoTo Start, GoTo strNumber1, GoTo strNumber2) that have no corresponding targets (Start:, strNumber1: etc).  Also, Else: should be Else ... no colon needed. Or wanted. Also, you've misspelled a couple of your variables either in the DIM statements or in code. Put OPTION EXPLICIT at the top of the module, then try to compile the code before running it.  That'll help you find/fix a bunch of other errors.

Answer (score 3):

- First thing first - never use GOTO. Only in error handling ([On Error statement (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement)).
- Second - if you need to use it, a mark is needed. E.g., if it is `GoTo somewhere`, then in the code it should be defined like this - `somewhere:`.

---

```
Sub DontUseGoTo()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

somewhere:
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
    If i < 10 Then
        GoTo somewhere
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]